# A few questions about icons

Tags: ios

I guess the answer will be this isn't possible, but I'd like to confirm and double check:

- Is it possible for an app to be installed without an icon? If so, could the app make it appear at a later stage programatically?
- Could two differing icons both launch the same app?

Comment: 1) No, and 2) possibly, if your app is registered to deal with certain URLs, and you can make icons that open those URLs, but I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Could you expand upon your second point please. Actually my app can currently be launched via a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### In the app store:

An app must be represented by an icon on the home screen. Without an icon file you get a white rounded rectangle with a glossy shine. If you later update it you can change the icon file.

Two app icons cannot launch the same app.

Are you familiar with home screen bookmarks? When the user bookmarks a website. With that and app URL schemes you could have two icons, but the user would have to add it themselves.

#### Outside of the app store

I'm unsure about how this could work on a jailbroken device.

Answer (score 0):

The app icon is part of the signed app so can not be changed. I seriously doubt Apple would approve an app with a blank icon.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer to ALL your questions is no.  Your second bullet point would be interesting but Apple definitely isn't going to let that happen!